# Export a range to new csv file, but the first row should be clear

Tags: excel, vba, csv, range, export

This code exports a range of values that I want to a new csv file, but it should start at row 2, so I can fill the first row with a headline (another range value).

```vb
Sub TestRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, fd As FileDialog, rngTest As Range, rngExport As Range, fltr As FileDialogFilter
    Dim start As Long
    start = 2
'    Dim jahr As Integer
    
'   jahr = Date
    
    'Nach jeweiliger Zeit wird Datenreihe (start ab) ausgewählt
    If Time < TimeValue("11:15") Then
        Do Until Daten.Range("ov" & start) = Date + 1
        start = start + 1
        Loop
    Else
        Do Until Daten.Range("ov" & start) = Date + 2
        start = start + 1
        Loop
    End If
    
    'Worksheet auf dem die Daten stehen
    Set ws = Worksheets("Daten")
    
    'Zelle die auf Inhalt überprüft werden soll
    Set rngTest = ws.Range("ov2")
    'Bereich der exportiert wird
    Set rngExport = ws.Range("ov" & start & ":ow5000")
    If rngTest.Text <> "" Then
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        'Filename
        fd.InitialFileName = "LG" & " " & Diagramm.Range("a5").Value & " " & "RZ" & " " & Format(Date, "mmmm") & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "_" & "MW" & "_" & "ab" & " " & Daten.Range("ov" & start).Value
       ' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show filenameComplete
        With fd
            .Title = ""
            'Filterindex für CSV-Dateien ermitteln
            For i = 1 To .Filters.count
                If .Filters(i).Extensions = "*.csv" Then
                    .FilterIndex = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            'Wenn OK geklickt wurde starte Export
            If .Show = True Then
                ExportRangeAsCSV rngExport, ";", .SelectedItems(1)
                
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

'Prozedur für den Export eines Ranges in eine CSV-Datei
Sub ExportRangeAsCSV(ByVal rng As Range, delim As String, filepath As String)
    Dim arr As Variant, line As String, csvContent As String, fso As Object, csvFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set csvFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, 2, True)
    
    arr = rng.Value 'Filter
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            line = ""
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If c < UBound(arr, 2) Then
                    line = line & """" & arr(r, c) & """" & delim
                Else
                    line = line & """" & arr(r, c) & """"
                End If
            Next
          
            csvContent = csvContent & line & vbNewLine
           
        Next
        
        csvFile.Write (csvContent)
        csvFile.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Bereich besteht nur aus einer Zelle!", vbExclamation
    End If
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set csvFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

I copied this code from the internet and it works, but I couldn't find a solution.

How can I change the code so my csv file has the first row clear, so that i can write the headlines of the two columns in the first row?

Comment: *I copied this code from the internet and it works,* -- in that case you must credit your source as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
If IsArray(arr) Then
        ' new code
        Dim col as range
        For Each col In rng.Columns
           If Len(line) > 0 Then line = line & delim
           line = line & """" & rng.Parent.Cells(1, col.Column) & """"
        Next
        csvContent = line & vbNewLine

        ' existing code
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
```